# Why isn't document.onload called?

Tags: javascript

By looking at the output of `console.log(document)`, I find `document` has these properties:`onload=null;onloadstart=null;onloadend=null;onreadystatechange=null;` I write the following code:

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
<script>
document.onload=function(){alert("document.onload");};
document.onloadstart=function(){alert("document.onloadstart");};
document.onloadend=function(){alert("document.onloadend");};
document.onreadystatechange=function(){alert("document.onreadystatechange");};
</script>
<div>hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Interestingly, `document.onload,document.onloadstart,document.onloadend` are never called, while `document.onreadystatechange` is called twice, why?

Comment: Why do you assume that `document` emits a `load` event?

Comment: And about `readystatechange` is your question why it is called for `document`, or why it is called twice?

Comment: @t.niese I can understand why document.onreadystatechange is called twice but cannot understand why document.onload is not called. If document does not emit onload at all, why document has that property?

Comment: see: [JS window.onload Usage Vs Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092746/js-window-onload-usage-vs-document)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't document.onload called?

First of all the `load` events (created by the browser) do not bubble (because that's how it is specified):

```js
document.body.onload = function(e) {
   console.dir(e.bubbles)
}
```

So you can only listen for these `load` events, on the element for which they occur.

And for [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document#events) there is no `load` event listed that will be triggered based on the standard.

[`readystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event) on the other hand is listed as an event that can happen for `document`.

You can however for sure listen for `load` events on the `document` and the event callback will be called. But that will only happen if you e.g. manually trigger one on `document`:

```js
const event = new Event('load');

document.onload = function (e) { 
   console.log('load document')
}

document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Or if you emit a `load` event that bubbles on a descendant:

```js
const event = new Event('load', {bubbles: true});

document.onload = function (e) { 
   console.log('load document')
}

document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
```

So why does `onload` then appear as a property? That's due to the [`GlobalEventHandlers`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#globaleventhandlers) and [`Document includes GlobalEventHandlers`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-document-object:globaleventhandlers)), and due to [event handler IDL attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes), exposing those as `on…` event properties.

Comment: I still have a little confusion. Looking at the output of document.body.onload = function(e) {
   console.dir(e);
}, you can see e.target is document not document.body. So, theoretically, the event should be handled by document.onload instead of document.body.onload. Why is document.body.onload instead of document.onload called?

Comment: @peter the `document.body.onload = function(e) {` was probably a bad example. If you look at [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element) `[...]The body element exposes as event handler content attributes a number of the event handlers of the Window object.[...]`. Why the target is `document` and not `window` is something I don't know. Maybe it dates back to the time of the "browser war" and now it can't be changed anymore without breaking many scripts.

Comment: Maybe the initial logic was the event says that the `document` is loaded, so the `target` of the event is the `document`, but if you have an "empty" window in which you want to load the `document` you would need to listen on the `window` (as the document does not exists yet).

Comment: [load, WIndow](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-load): `Fired at the Window when the document has finished loading; fired at an element containing a resource (e.g. img, embed) when it resource has finished loading` So the logic is likely to be `window` is the element containing a resource, `document` the resource.

Answer (score 1):

`.onload` is part of the `window` object, not for `document`.
[GlobalEventHandlers.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

> The onload property of the GlobalEventHandlers mixin is an event handler that processes `load` events on a `Window`, `XMLHttpRequest`, `<iframe>` and `<img>` elements, etc.

And from what i've seen on MDN `.onloadstart` and `.onloadend` are used for resources like images, don't know if they are availiable for `document`/`window`. [GlobalEventHandlers.onloadstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onloadstart)

But I think with `onreadystatechange` you should be able to emulate the behavior of `onloadstart` and `onloadend`.
[Document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)

Comment: But console.log(document) shows .onload is there, together with .onloadstart and .onloadend.

Comment: @peter You can add any property you like to an element, but that doesn't mean it will do anything. In general it is recommended to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add listeners rather than the inline attributes.

Comment: @pilchard `it is recommended to use addEventListener to add listeners` I fully agree with that. And also with `You can add any property you like to an`. The OP is likely referring to `document.onload` to already existing (it is set to `null`) by default.

Comment: @t.niese ah, I see, yes both Document and Window implement the `GlobalEventHandlers` mixin but as you noted that doesn't mean they necessarily fire.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure, but try this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    alert("document.onload")
})
```

I only use window onload event, but if I never saw document onload event, just change `window` to `document`.

Like I said´, I'm unsure what to do, because the amount of your code, which you showed is to less.